# JQuery UI autocomplete error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

when I start typing product names into the textbox I get the following error in my console output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of null jquery-ui.js:45
a.extend.filter jquery-ui.js:45
e.extend.grep jquery.js:2
a.extend.filter jquery-ui.js:45
a.widget._initSource.a.isArray.source jquery-ui.js:45
a.widget._search jquery-ui.js:45
a.widget.search jquery-ui.js:45
(anonymous function)
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('document').ready(function() {

    var products = <?php echo json_encode($products_arr); ?>;

    console.log(products); //products are displayed ok
   $("#product").autocomplete({
      source: products
   });
 });
</script>
```

My jquery works as I've tried the example in the the jquery docs.

I stepped through my `products` array limiting my sql results to 10 results at a time and it began to work until i got to 66. In the JS console output it shows me a `null` entry.

```
.."PN", null, "SS"]
```

I did remove all empty/null values which appears to fix it but can someone tell me why this might happen? I don't have any empty records in the DB.

Comment: `$products_arr` has `null` in it. Code just doesn't lie.

Comment: @xdazz: Yes, I get that. I found the record that appeared as `null` in the js array and mapped it to the record in the database. The record did exist, however after merely rewriting it (via edit), the `null` value appears to have disappeared from the js array.

Comment: why not try replace null or is_null to zero?